# "Cash on me" vs. "cash with me"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I know you would normally say, "I don't have any cash on me". But would it be grammatically correct to say, "I don't have any cash with me"?

Comment: Sorry Mohammad, but this question seems like [proofreading](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proofreading) which is off topic, as defined in [the faq](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). For this question to be on topic, it needs to be edited in such a way that you are not asking "does anything look wrong with this?"

Comment: Having said that, do feel free to [come into chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage) and ask such questions.

Comment: While "on" is more common in informal speech, "with" is probably more common in formal writing.  So not only may you use "with", but it's preferable in many settings.

Comment: @MattЭллен, I don't think it's off-topic.  It sounds like a case where informal usage has become so common that someone wonders if the original, formal usage is even correct.  That seems like a valid question to me, not proof-reading.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I agree, now that Reg has edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are grammatical and both are found, but *cash on me* is probably more frequent in speech.

Comment: 8 seconds ahead of me. :(

Comment: @IntermediateHacker hackers are know for their speed of writing, shame on you :D By the way some off topic question recommendations for good dictionary of phrasal verbs ?

Comment: @Barrie Could you explain it in details? I am looking for a more in depth kind of explanation.

Comment: @Mohammad: There's little to add. You can use either, but native speakers would probably use 'on me' more often than 'with me'.

Comment: Yes. *"no cash on me"* outweighs *"no cash with me"* by over 3:1 in Google Books.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: How about this: I didn't bring any cash on me. Or I didn't bring any cash with me. Ideas?

Comment: @Mohammad: No, you can only say 'I didn't bring any cash with me'. 'Bring' collocates with 'with', not 'on'.

Answer (score 5):

As Barrie England suggests, *cash on me* is probably more common in speech, but *cash with me* would have a slightly broader meaning. *Cash on me* would mean cash about my person, in my pockets, boots, wrapped in my handkerchief, or something of that nature. *Cash with me* might also include in my suitcase, in my car or caravan, or anywhere else near to hand but not necessarily about my person.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a decent reference (okay, ANY reference) but this matches up with what I understand and use the on/with distinction as well more broadly as well... example - if I was told that a person had a pigeon *on* them, I'd be looking for the pigeon sitting on their head/shoulder. For a pigeon *with* them, I'd be looking at the small pigeon-sized box they're holding or they'd be telling me about their pet pigeon back at the hotel room.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, I think both are correct.

> I don't have any cash with me.

Seems all right to me, since people also use,

> I haven't brought the cash with me.

I'll try to find some reference to the usage on the internet or my Oxford Dictionary.